# SQL table data horizontally using PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My SQL table is

```
  GUID               Step_ID        Value
----------------------------------------------
ADFE12-ASDER-...      1             10
ADFE12-ASDER-...      2             20
ADFE12-ASDER-...      3             30
ADFE12-ASDER-...      4             160
CD4563-FG567-...      1             20
CD4563-FG567-...      2             80
Q23RT5-GH678...       1             30
Q23RT5-GH678-...      2             80
Q23RT5-GH678-...      3             20
```

And Expected result should be

```
GUID                  1        2        3        4
---------------------------------------------------
ADFE12-ASDER-...      10       20       30       160
CD4563-FG567-...      20       80      NULL     NULL
Q23RT5-GH678-...      30       80      20       NULL
```

Here I need to get the details on the basis of column whose data type is GUID. I tried using PIVOT table but getting an exception because I cannot use an aggregate function on GUID column. Is there any other alternative or approach I can use to get the above desired result.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: convert the GUID to varchar(36)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select [GUID],[1],[2],[3],[4]
from
(
  select [GUID], Step_ID, Value
  from test
) d
pivot
(
  max(Value)
  for Step_ID in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) piv;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a148/2)**

Answer (score 1):

You could try manually pivotting, I don't have a SQL Server handy to check the behavior on a GUID but this has worked well for me in the past.

```
select  guid, 
        max(case when step_ID = 1 then value else null end) step_1,
        max(case when step_ID = 2 then value else null end) step_2,
        max(case when step_ID = 3 then value else null end) step_3,
        max(case when step_ID = 4 then value else null end) step_4
  from  your_table
  group by guid;
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks Rohit and Steven for all your help. I have checked the solutions provided by you guys and it gives me the expected result.